# SQL Server Merge rows using lag?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, lag

i have a table that , have Intime, OutTime,  zonechk flag

if 1 mean inside , null mean outside  , i need to merge them for reporting Propose for example

inside 10:10 to 10:40

inside 11:10 to 12:30

outside 12:31 to 14:00

inside 14:10 to 14:40

inside 15:10 to 15:30

to be

inside 10:10 to 12:30

outside 12:31 to 14:00

inside 14:10 to 15:40

```
+--------+--------------+----------------+--------------+----------+-------------------------+--------+---------+
| Number | plate_number | move_from_date | move_to_date | Duration |         inTime          | zoneid | zonechk |
+--------+--------------+----------------+--------------+----------+-------------------------+--------+---------+
|   5934 | NULL         |     1507713204 |   1508147403 |   434199 | 2017-10-11 09:13:24.100 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1507793515 |   1507793924 |      409 | 2017-10-12 07:31:55.310 |    709 | NULL    |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1508051465 |   1508051861 |      396 | 2017-10-15 07:11:05.010 |    709 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1508139025 |   1508139551 |      526 | 2017-10-16 07:30:25.570 |    709 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1508147732 |   1508148337 |      605 | 2017-10-16 09:55:32.650 |    698 | NULL    |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1508148802 |   1508235374 |    86572 | 2017-10-16 10:13:22.060 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1508227127 |   1508227707 |      580 | 2017-10-17 07:58:47.040 |    709 | NULL    |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1508235727 |   1508236062 |      335 | 2017-10-17 10:22:07.150 |    698 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1508236426 |   1508320755 |    84329 | 2017-10-17 10:33:46.040 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1508312035 |   1508312473 |      438 | 2017-10-18 07:33:55.780 |    709 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1508321089 |   1508321767 |      678 | 2017-10-18 10:04:49.110 |    698 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1508322313 |   1508405959 |    83646 | 2017-10-18 10:25:13.990 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1508398316 |   1508398778 |      462 | 2017-10-19 07:31:56.680 |    709 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1508406309 |   1508406811 |      502 | 2017-10-19 09:45:09.260 |    698 | NULL    |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1508407153 |   1508575805 |   168652 | 2017-10-19 09:59:13.857 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1508565909 |   1508566376 |      467 | 2017-10-21 06:05:09.240 |    709 | NULL    |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1508576176 |   1508576601 |      425 | 2017-10-21 08:56:16.473 |    698 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1508577010 |   1508834353 |   257343 | 2017-10-21 09:10:10.710 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1508584759 |   1508585455 |      696 | 2017-10-21 11:19:19.930 |    709 | NULL    |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1508659492 |   1508660021 |      529 | 2017-10-22 08:04:52.490 |    709 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1508741980 |   1508742462 |      482 | 2017-10-23 06:59:40.960 |    709 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1508749508 |   1508750050 |      542 | 2017-10-23 09:05:08.893 |    709 | NULL    |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1508834742 |   1508835409 |      667 | 2017-10-24 08:45:42.960 |    698 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1508917280 |   1508917694 |      414 | 2017-10-25 07:41:20.940 |    709 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1508966861 |   1509000828 |    33967 | 2017-10-25 21:27:41.490 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509000911 |   1509002958 |     2047 | 2017-10-26 06:55:11.330 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509001844 |   1509002376 |      532 | 2017-10-26 07:10:44.090 |    709 | NULL    |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509003211 |   1509007113 |     3902 | 2017-10-26 07:33:31.023 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509006789 |   1509006863 |       74 | 2017-10-26 08:33:09.350 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509006866 |   1509007049 |      183 | 2017-10-26 08:34:26.130 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509007257 |   1509009354 |     2097 | 2017-10-26 08:40:57.170 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509008978 |   1509009089 |      111 | 2017-10-26 09:09:38.660 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509009092 |   1509009231 |      139 | 2017-10-26 09:11:32.420 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509009458 |   1509009946 |      488 | 2017-10-26 09:17:38.590 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509009529 |   1509009608 |       79 | 2017-10-26 09:18:49.600 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509009610 |   1509009757 |      147 | 2017-10-26 09:20:10.990 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509009759 |   1509009909 |      150 | 2017-10-26 09:22:39.610 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509010472 |   1509010787 |      315 | 2017-10-26 09:34:32.270 |    698 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509011192 |   1509011367 |      175 | 2017-10-26 09:46:32.530 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509011370 |   1509011424 |       54 | 2017-10-26 09:49:30.100 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509011644 |   1509016547 |     4903 | 2017-10-26 09:54:04.390 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509016793 |   1509018783 |     1990 | 2017-10-26 11:19:53.370 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509018880 |   1509021232 |     2352 | 2017-10-26 11:54:40.680 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509021327 |   1509041423 |    20096 | 2017-10-26 12:35:27.760 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509042027 |   1509179109 |   137082 | 2017-10-26 18:20:27.460 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509174809 |   1509175309 |      500 | 2017-10-28 07:13:29.010 |    709 | NULL    |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509179335 |   1509179907 |      572 | 2017-10-28 08:28:55.660 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509180005 |   1509180828 |      823 | 2017-10-28 08:40:05.890 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509180925 |   1509187555 |     6630 | 2017-10-28 08:55:25.270 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509187624 |   1509189851 |     2227 | 2017-10-28 10:47:04.630 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509190143 |   1509190301 |      158 | 2017-10-28 11:29:03.580 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509190387 |   1509191479 |     1092 | 2017-10-28 11:33:07.230 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509191575 |   1509192224 |      649 | 2017-10-28 11:52:55.150 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509192314 |   1509192479 |      165 | 2017-10-28 12:05:14.800 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509192588 |   1509218423 |    25835 | 2017-10-28 12:09:48.670 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509219048 |   1509224551 |     5503 | 2017-10-28 19:30:48.440 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509225176 |   1509260681 |    35505 | 2017-10-28 21:12:56.600 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509260770 |   1509269210 |     8440 | 2017-10-29 07:06:10.840 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509261874 |   1509262382 |      508 | 2017-10-29 07:24:34.730 |    709 | NULL    |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509269612 |   1509270116 |      504 | 2017-10-29 09:33:32.580 |    698 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509270123 |   1509270136 |       13 | 2017-10-29 09:42:03.510 |    698 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509270499 |   1509271818 |     1319 | 2017-10-29 09:48:19.940 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509271880 |   1509272029 |      149 | 2017-10-29 10:11:20.030 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509339400 |   1509348800 |     9400 | 2017-10-30 04:56:40.890 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509348868 |   1509350133 |     1265 | 2017-10-30 07:34:28.720 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509349430 |   1509349892 |      462 | 2017-10-30 07:43:50.690 |    709 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509350202 |   1509352410 |     2208 | 2017-10-30 07:56:42.050 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509352779 |   1509353737 |      958 | 2017-10-30 08:39:39.040 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509353800 |   1509354320 |      520 | 2017-10-30 08:56:40.150 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509354782 |   1509358601 |     3819 | 2017-10-30 09:13:02.250 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509359418 |   1509432505 |    73087 | 2017-10-30 10:30:18.960 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509432786 |   1509432917 |      131 | 2017-10-31 06:53:06.880 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509432999 |   1509433705 |      706 | 2017-10-31 06:56:39.133 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509433790 |   1509438679 |     4889 | 2017-10-31 07:09:50.570 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509438792 |   1509438859 |       67 | 2017-10-31 08:33:12.063 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509438962 |   1509441624 |     2662 | 2017-10-31 08:36:02.810 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509443082 |   1509443985 |      903 | 2017-10-31 09:44:42.670 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509443897 |   1509443930 |       33 | 2017-10-31 09:58:17.230 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509444103 |   1509447041 |     2938 | 2017-10-31 10:01:43.537 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509447618 |   1509450979 |     3361 | 2017-10-31 11:00:18.440 |     54 | 1       |
|   5934 | NULL         |     1509451066 |   1509451371 |      305 | 2017-10-31 11:57:46.560 |     54 | 1       |
+--------+--------------+----------------+--------------+----------+-------------------------+--------+---------+
```

how to achieve that using lag  with delete in TSQL ? lag must be by number and zoneId with inTime ASC

Comment: For the sample data posted, could you show the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `cross apply` can be helpful here, e.g.

available as a demo at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/960a5/6)

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([Number] int, [plate_number] varchar(4), [move_from_date] int, [move_to_date] int, [Duration] int, [inTime] datetime, [zoneid] int, [zonechk] varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([Number], [plate_number], [move_from_date], [move_to_date], [Duration], [inTime], [zoneid], [zonechk])
VALUES
    (5934, NULL, 1507713204, 1508147403, 434199, '2017-10-11 09:13:24', 54, '1'),
    (5934, NULL, 1507793515, 1507793924, 409, '2017-10-12 07:31:55', 709, NULL),
    (5934, NULL, 1508051465, 1508051861, 396, '2017-10-15 07:11:05', 709, '1'),
    (5934, NULL, 1508139025, 1508139551, 526, '2017-10-16 07:30:25', 709, '1'),
    (5934, NULL, 1508147732, 1508148337, 605, '2017-10-16 09:55:32', 698, NULL),
    (5934, NULL, 1508148802, 1508235374, 86572, '2017-10-16 10:13:22', 54, '1'),
    (5934, NULL, 1508227127, 1508227707, 580, '2017-10-17 07:58:47', 709, NULL),
    (5934, NULL, 1508235727, 1508236062, 335, '2017-10-17 10:22:07', 698, '1')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
*
from table1 t
cross apply (
  select top(1) move_to_date as next_move_to
  from table1 nxt
  where nxt.zonechk IS NULL
  and nxt.move_to_date > t.move_from_date
  order by nxt.move_from_date, nxt.move_to_date
  ) ca
where zonechk = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/960a5/6/0)**:

```
| Number | plate_number | move_from_date | move_to_date | Duration |               inTime | zoneid | zonechk | next_move_to |
|--------|--------------|----------------|--------------|----------|----------------------|--------|---------|--------------|
|   5934 |       (null) |     1507713204 |   1508147403 |   434199 | 2017-10-11T09:13:24Z |     54 |       1 |   1507793924 |
|   5934 |       (null) |     1508051465 |   1508051861 |      396 | 2017-10-15T07:11:05Z |    709 |       1 |   1508148337 |
|   5934 |       (null) |     1508139025 |   1508139551 |      526 | 2017-10-16T07:30:25Z |    709 |       1 |   1508148337 |
|   5934 |       (null) |     1508148802 |   1508235374 |    86572 | 2017-10-16T10:13:22Z |     54 |       1 |   1508227707 |
```

Comment: More facts about your expected result would be useful.